# Prevent PlayFramework's template engine from escaping my Strings

Tags: scala, templates, playframework-2.1

I've created some utilities that help me at generating HTML and I reference them in my views as `@div( "class" -> "well" ){ Hello Well. }`. Until now those classes were subclassing `NodeSeq` because they [aren't escaped](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/702d48bf4d9d24b58f247546b0cd0cb893659dc0/framework/src/templates/src/main/scala/play/api/templates/ScalaTemplate.scala#L71) then. But I need to get rid off the `NodeSeq` in the top of my class hierarchy because Scala's xml is flawed and makes my code hacky and because I could switch to Traits then.

So I tried to find out how to prevent Play from escaping my `Tag`-objects. But unfortunately the only valid solution that I found is to override the template compiler and have the user specify my compiler in his `Build.scala` settings.

But I hopefully have overlooked a way more simple approach?

Comment: I'm a little unsure what you mean (example code for your tag helpers would help) but my first thought is that you need to use `@Html("<span>stuff that won't be escaped</span>")`? Can you elaborate?

Comment: I'm basically building a custom template engine on top of Play's engine. Therefore wrapping my calls with `@Html` is not an option. http://taig.github.io/Play-Tmpltr/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since version `2.2.0-M1` there appeared a new approach in the docs that explains how to add custom formats to the template engine. This allows me to easily integrate my utilities.

**Custom Template Format:** [Java](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.0-M1/JavaCustomTemplateFormat), [Scala](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.0-M1/ScalaCustomTemplateFormat)

Comment: (both links are broken)

Answer (score 3):

If your html helpers returns 'Html' rather than String you don't need to wrap them using the @Html tag in the view.

eg

```
import play.api.templates.Html

def a(src: String, value: String) : Html = Html(s"<a href='$src'>$value</a>")
```

Would be called in the view as below without needing to wrap in @Html

```
@a("www.example.com", "Example")
```

Comment: This is a good approach, but unfortunately my helper `@div` is a class that is being rendered by Play via its `toString` method.